# Fedora 26 strange calendar/date and SELinux bahaviour after Kernel update

Tags: linux, fedora, updates, kernel, date

Yesterday I've installed all of the latest official updates for Fedora 26 64-bit Workstation, including 4.12 Kernel update.
After the system restart, SELinux is reporting following problems:

The source process:     sm-notify, unix_chkpwd, accounts-daemon, systemd-tmpfile
Attempted this access:  dac_read_search

Also, the calendar on my LXDE panel is showing "null" values, and a "date" command in the terminal is displaying strange characters instead of Polish letters (my LC_TIME is set to Polish).
Please check the attached images:
[image: calendar] and 
[image: "date" output].
Do you have any suggestions about what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out myself.
You can fix the SELinux problems by running "dnf update" again and installing remaining updates which were waiting, and restarting the system - after that I get no SELinux error reports.
To fix the Polish characters in the "date" command and on the LXDE calendar I just had to set "LANG" system variable to "en_US.utf8" and then set "LC_TIME" to "pl_PL.utf8" back again (sudo localectl set-locale LC_TIME=pl_PL.utf8).
Also, after installing the updates, TeamViewer stopped working, it just didn't run. To make it work, I've uninstalled it, then manually removed remaining TeamViewer folders from /home/*/.config and /home/*/.local/share and installed it - now it works.